# What do the (+) and (-) symbols after variables mean?

Tags: terminology, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

This paper describing an Unscented Kalman Filter implementation uses notation that I am unfamiliar with nor can find on eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

[Xu et al (2008)](http://serv.yanchick.org/Books/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9/acc08/data/papers/0551.pdf)

An example line is:

$$\chi_{i,k-1}(+) = f(\chi_{i,k-1}), x_k(-)=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\omega_i\chi_{i,k-1}(+)$$

This notation continues throughout the paper.

Could someone please tell me what the (+) and (-) indicate? At first I thought it was redundant information describing the post and prior versions of $x$ however one of them is $\chi$ and the other is $x$. I also thought it could be the positive and negative solutions of a square root but that isn't obvious to me as being correct either (why (+) of $\chi$ and (-) of $x$ and where are the other solutions).

Comment: They seem to refer to the *a priori* and *a posteriori* estimate. Compare the equations with [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Predict), Wikipedia uses $x_{k\mid k-1}$ where your paper uses $x_k(-)$ and $x_{k\mid k}$ instead of $x_k(+)$.

Comment: @N74. Thank you. That seems correct to me. (Although noting that they are using chi for the sigma points in the unscented version of the kalman filter.). It would be good if I could accept this as the answer.

Comment: I copied it in the answer block, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to refer to the a priori and a posteriori estimate. Compare the equations with [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Predict), Wikipedia uses $x_{k∣k−1}$ where your paper uses $x_k(−)$ and $x_{k∣k}$ instead of $x_k(+)$.